# vdc to vac inverters

Tags: electrical

I have four 12v 7ah sla batteries in series and parallel and ups 500 battery back up transformer.I want to power universal washing motor for bicycle.I need 120vac anywhere from 300/500 watts and 5/9amps.my ? is would anyone be able to in the simplest way draw diagram/schematic I have maybe all i need to assemble inverter mosfets transistors caps diodes heatsinks etc just need to know circuit diagram i searched but found little info.Can somebody please help?

Comment: Designing an inverter is not trivial. Remember that motors need inrush capability from the inverter, so you may briefly have to handle large currents. I don't think explaining you how to build one is a good fit for SE's format, as it's probably a book length tutorial.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. This isn't on-topic here. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about home improvement.

Comment: It's going to be far less of a headache just buying a COTS inverter...

Comment: I would advise moving this question to electrical engineering SE, but they're not half as nice as we are, and they'll cut you to ribbons for the poor writing quality, speech to text or whatever that is, and for expressing yourself as very low on the learning curve for what is a complex project.

Answer (score 1):

I understand the concept of *saving $$$* and time by coming on this site by asking questions for help.

But your question sir sounds to me more like a electrical engineering inquiry. Again, I get your angle, but I would not hang my hat on someone giving you design specs for a home made ups system.

Just imagine if something was overlooked. I did a lot of ups installs 3 phase / single phase and anything we ever bought was off the shelf which had inherent protection designed right in the system.

Big or small, I recommend an off-shelf readily engineered system.